# When might the mean of PCA be useful?

Tags: pca

I wish for a better understanding of the mean from principal component analysis. I am told this merely projects the origin to a different  coordinate space. However, is there use to using the mean from principal components, I am usually taught to use the variance explained.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi welcome to the site! What do you mean by mean?

Comment: @JohnMadden Thank you! I am specifically referring to the `mean_` attribute from `sklearn` for `PCA`: [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html says "**mean_ndarray of shape (n_features,)**     Per-feature empirical mean, estimated from the training set.     Equal to `X.mean(axis=0)`."  You may want this so you can manually centre test set data to match your model or for some other reason